# ImportError from subdirectory

Tags: python, windows

I am getting an import error when a module in a sub-directory imports from another module in the same directory. I believe the error is arising because of permissions on the computer however I am having trouble diagnosing this. The folder structure is as follows.

```
/test_import
    test.py
    /imports
        __init__.py
        aa.py
        bb.py
```

With bb.py containing

```
from aa import myfun
```

aa.py containing

```
def myfun():
    print("hello")
```

and test.py containing

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from imports import bb
    bb.myfun()
```

on my computer when running the following I am getting expected results

```
C:\Users\mgilbert\test_import>python test.py
hello
```

However on a different box I am getting the following error

[image: import error]

for whatever reason when I try to run >python test.py this causes an import error however if I start ipython and do the relevant imports this works fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using implicit relative imports.  These [no longer exist in Python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) because they're frankly more trouble than they're worth.

Change the import in `bb.py` to this:

```
from imports.aa import myfun
```

Comment: Thanks! This resolved the issue. Any idea why this error occurs sporadically? I.e works on one machine and not another? Also, if my function bb.py is named imports.py this seems to cause issues, is it best to use the dot notation in this case? i.e. from .aa import myfun

Comment: I don't see any obvious reason why that should be.  But implicit relative imports are widely considered evil.